# Merge two response data in one - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a NodeJS server that takes data from two different API's, and then I want to combine the result from both in one JSON response. Here I am sending you the code:

```
EventModal.eventSearch(eventReq, type, async function (eventRes) {
       EventModal.getBoostEvents(eventReq, type, async function (eventBoostRes) {
                           res.json({
                                status: true,
                                data: eventRes,
                                eventBoostRes: eventBoostRes,
                            });
        });
  });
```

I want `eventRes` and `eventBoostRes` in one response in `data`.So how can I achieve that ?

`eventRes` and `eventBoostRes` are query result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you expand on what `eventRes` and `eventBoostRes` contain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: In JS everything is as simple as `obj.key=val` where val can be a js assignable entity like a integer, object or even function. It csn be also `obj[key]=val` where key can be a variable

Comment: `res.json({
                                status: true,
                                data: {eventRes:eventRes,
                                eventBoostRes: eventBoostRes}
                            })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question not very clear.

However, it sounds like you are getting 2 arrays and you want to return a single array in the response. Quick ( and dirty ) way to do this is use `array.concat( anotherArray )` function:

```
EventModal.eventSearch(eventReq, type, async function (eventRes) {
    EventModal.getBoostEvents(eventReq, type, async function (eventBoostRes) {
        res.json({
            status: true,
            data: eventRes.concat( eventBoostRes )
        });
    });
});
```

However, this will cause 2 queries to run in sync and is not optimal. You could optimise this to use promises and run 2 queries in parallel:

```
Promise.all([ // this will run in parallel
  EventModal.eventSearch(eventReq, type),
  EventModal.getBoostEvents( eventReq, type )
]).then( function onSuccess([ eventRes, eventBoostRes ]) {
  res.json({
    status: true,
    data: eventRes.concat( eventBoostRes )
  });
});
```

On the other hand; this should probably be handled at the query level.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them like this:

```
EventModal.eventSearch(eventReq, type, async function (eventRes) {
    EventModal.getBoostEvents(eventReq, type, async function (eventBoostRes) {
        res.json({
            status: true,
            data: { 
                eventRes, 
                eventBoostRes
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it contains in different array object. So I need to make modification in response.

Comment: Can you paste what `eventRes` and `eventBoostRes` could look like? And paste the result you want `data` to contain in the response?